# Authentication error attempting to sign data with EC private key from Secure Enclave

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography, commoncrypto

I'm attempting to do the following in my iOS application:

1. Generate a key pair using `SecKeyGeneratePair`, storing the private key in the Secure Enclave
2. Sign some data using the private key

It works if I hang on to the private key reference when keys are first generated, but does not work if I attempt to retrieve the reference from the Keychain after discarding the initial pointer.

The keys are generated like this:

```
func generateKeyPair() -> Bool {

    if let access = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(nil,
                                                    kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
                                                    [.userPresence, .privateKeyUsage],
                                                    nil) {

        let privateKeyAttr = [kSecAttrIsPermanent : 1,
                              kSecAttrApplicationTag : privateTag,
                              kSecAttrAccessControl as String: access
            ] as NSDictionary

        let publicKeyAttr = [kSecAttrIsPermanent : 0,
                             kSecAttrApplicationTag : publicTag
            ] as NSDictionary

        let keyPairAttr = [kSecAttrKeySizeInBits : 256,
                           kSecAttrKeyType : kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,
                           kSecAttrTokenID as String: kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
                           kSecPrivateKeyAttrs : privateKeyAttr,
                           kSecPublicKeyAttrs : publicKeyAttr] as NSDictionary

        let err = SecKeyGeneratePair(keyPairAttr, &publicKey, &privateKey)
        return err == noErr
}
```

The signing method is below:

```
func signData(plainText: Data) -> NSData? {                
    guard privateKey != nil else {
        print("Private key unavailable")
        return nil
    }

    let digestToSign = self.sha1DigestForData(data: plainText as NSData) as Data

    let signature = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 128)
    var signatureLength = 128
    let err = SecKeyRawSign(privateKey!,
                            .PKCS1SHA1,
                            [UInt8](digestToSign),
                            Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH),
                            signature,
                            &signatureLength)

    print("Signature status: \(err)")

    let sigData = NSData(bytes: signature, length: Int(signatureLength))

    return sigData
}

func sha1DigestForData(data: NSData) -> NSData {
    let len = Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    let digest = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: len)
    CC_SHA1(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), digest)
    return NSData(bytesNoCopy: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(digest), length: len)
}
```

This asks for my fingerprint and works flawlessly. I then use another method to get the key reference from the Keychain:

```
func getPrivateKeyRef() -> SecKey? {

    let parameters = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: privateTag,
        kSecReturnRef as String: true,
        ] as [String : Any]
    var ref: AnyObject?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(parameters as CFDictionary, &ref)
    print("Get key status: \(status)")

    if status == errSecSuccess { return ref as! SecKey? } else { return nil }
}
```

The `SecItemCopyMatching` returns a success status, but attempting to use the resulting `SecKey` item as a private key in `SecKeyRawSign` results in error `-25293 Authorization/Authentication failed.` This status only appears after I provide my fingerprint, so the actual fingerprint verification succeeds, but the key somehow remains unusable.

What is the correct way to use a key stored in Secure Enclave to sign data?

Comment: Were you able to get it work? I got the same issue, SecItemCopyMatch is successful, but no fingerprint dialog is prompt and SecKeyRawSign fails.

Comment: @Krypton yes, see my self-answer below for how I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using `kSecAttrLabel` attribute is necessary for correct fetching of the key. It must be specified when generating the keys, and when fetching them through `SecItemCopyMatching`.

My working solution for fetching the private key:

```
func getPrivateKey() -> SecKey? {
    let parameters = [
        kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrKeyClass as String: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String : "privateTag",
        kSecAttrLabel as String : "privateTag",
        kSecReturnRef as String: true,
        ] as [String : Any]
    var ref: AnyObject?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(parameters as CFDictionary, &ref)
    if status == errSecSuccess {
        return (ref as! SecKey)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Where the key pair was generated like this:

```
    var publicKey:SecKey?
    var privateKey:SecKey?
    if let access = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(nil,
                                                    kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
                                                    [.userPresence, .privateKeyUsage],
                                                    nil) {

        let privateKeyAttr = [kSecAttrIsPermanent : 1,
                              kSecAttrApplicationTag as String : "privateTag",
                              kSecAttrLabel as String : "privateTag",
                              kSecAttrAccessControl as String: access
            ] as NSDictionary

        let publicKeyAttr = [kSecAttrIsPermanent : 0,
                             kSecAttrApplicationTag as String : "publicTag",
                             kSecAttrLabel as String : "publicTag",
                             ] as NSDictionary

        // only 256 bit EC keys are supported in the Secure Enclave
        let keyPairAttr = [kSecAttrKeySizeInBits : 256,
                           kSecAttrKeyType : kSecAttrKeyTypeEC,
                           kSecAttrTokenID as String: kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
                           kSecPrivateKeyAttrs : privateKeyAttr,
                           kSecPublicKeyAttrs : publicKeyAttr] as NSDictionary

        let err = SecKeyGeneratePair(keyPairAttr, &publicKey, &privateKey)
```